# HTML Emails - Align text vertically centered

Tags: html, css, responsive-emails

I'm trying to vertically align the text in my JS fiddle so it is in the middle of the image.

I want to use tables so that I can control where they align for when they stack.

I know this is possible if the tables were TD's

Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/xfswnf2n/1/

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" width="400" style="vertically-align:middle;">
      <table align="left" width="190" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="display: table-cell">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="vertical-align:top;">ello</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table align="right" width="190" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="display: table-cell">
        <tr>
          <td><img src  alt=""></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You will need to use a background-image if you want text overlaying I think.

Comment: do you really need those two nested tables?

Comment: DaFois, I did mention in my question, to further expand on that I need them so I can use the align="" attribute to align them left and right. I need to do this so on mobile they stack in order. and i can use the left and right to create a layout that can alternator.